# How can I prompt a user to confirm before submitting an Action?

Tags: palantir-foundry, foundry-actions

I am trying to configure an action in the ontology manager application. This action edits objects that are currently used in production, so we need to make sure that users to not accidentally submit actions. As such, I would like to configure an extra pop up that will ask the user for explicit confirmation before the action submission goes through. Is this possible? Ideally it would look something like the confirmation popup that is shown by Foundry when you try to delete a dataset (see screenshot below).[image]

Answer (score 1, accepted):

Within the action form you could add another parameter asking the user to confirm with a specific word (e.g. 'I Acknowledge') that they really want to make those changes. I drafted this up in a Workshop app.
[image: Form Content Screen]
[image: Parameter Page]
[image: Error Example]
[image: Correctly Implemented]